# Sessão em Laravel não funciona em outra página

Tags: php, laravel, session

Estou trabalhando em um projeto com laravel, nele criei uma variavel de sessão que pega um parâmetro da url da seguinte forma:

```
if(!empty(Input::get('lang'))){
    $lang = Input::get('lang');
    Session::put('lang', $lang);

} else {
    $lang = "es";
    Session::put('lang', $lang);
}

if(Session::get('lang') == 'pt-br'){
    App::setLocale("pt-br");
}
```

Dessa forma a sessão só está funcionando nessa página, quando tento usar em outra página não consigo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Veja na pasta config o arquivo session.php e veja sua lifetime.

Comment: Está com o valor padrão, 120. Mesmo que eu altere para um valor bem alto continua do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Ela vem vazia na outra página ?

Comment: O retorno é NULL.

Comment: Tem algum erro de lógica ai! verifique melhor o código, ou então coloque todo o código!

Comment: @LucianoAlexandre uma dica seria você criar um middleware para fazer esse tratamento do idioma, no middleware você pode pegar o parâmetro lang na URL e setar o idioma correto e caso não tenha o parâmetro você seta o idioma default.

Answer (score 1):

A *session()* do Laravel trabalha de diversas maneiras, como podemos ver na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session). Contudo, se está usando a forma padrão será necessário dar um **reflash()** ou um **keep()** em sua sessão para manter em uma próxima página:

```
$request->session()->reflash();
```

ou

```
$request->session()->keep('lang');
```

Utilizando o *$request* como a variável da requisição.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Ajudou sim, mas poderia me esclarecer mais um detalhe, o que é uma variável de requisição? Como faço para usar?

Comment: Claro! Essa variável já vem automático em uma requisição quanto dá um *get* lá em seu routes.php. Vou postar um exemplo...

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo... lá no seu arquivo de rotas há um *get* para um determinado controller, certo? com uma função, por exemplo *listar*. Na função dentro do controller a função *listar* deverá estar da forma que está aqui neste aquivo, com a variável *request*: https://gist.github.com/evertramos/860bba5f8a4c672c829d662af3fc3b13 veja esse modelo.

Comment: É possivel criar uma variável de sessão sem usar uma variável de requisição?

Comment: A variável de requisição é padrão do Laravel... não sei se tem como criar a variável de sessão fora da requisição, pois a sessão está gravada justamente na requisição de vai e volta do cliente.

Comment: Ao tentar usa-la estou recebendo o seguinte erro: Argument 1 passed to HomeController::updateIdioma() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given

Comment: Um detalhe que pode ser importante é que estou usando a versão 4.2 do laravel.

Comment: Tem de referenciar no Controller. Eu uso 5.2

Comment: O meu código está assim no controller:                                                                                                         public function updateIdioma(Request $resquest){
            if(!empty(Input::get('lang'))){
                    $lang = Input::get('lang');
                    $langAtual = $request->session()->get($lang);
                return   View::make('auth.registration');                                                                                }
        }

Comment: Tente fazer os modelos da documentação e a parir de lá parta para os exemplos antes de colocar em produção.

Comment: Acredito que essa estrutura não é compativel com a versão 4.2.

Comment: Não entendi o porque de usar `reflash`, sendo que o AP não usa `flash` em nenhuma parte do código.  Quando se usa `put`, a sessão deveria funcionar com  `get` normalmente.